# AWS Lambda Chalice Layers Segmentation Fault

Tags: aws-lambda, segmentation-fault, aws-lambda-layers, chalice, aws-data-wrangler

I am deploying a Python 3.7 Lambda function via Chalice. Because the code with its environment requirements, is larger than 50 MB limit, I am using the "automatic_layer" feature of Chalice to generate the layer with the requirements, which is `awswrangler`.

Because the generated layer is > 50 MB, I am uploading the generated `managed-layer-...-python3.7.zip` manually to s3 and create a Lambda layer. Then I re-deploy with chalice, removing the `automatic_layer` option and setting the `layers` to the generated ARN of the layer I manually created.

The function deployed this way worked OK for a couple of times, then started failing occasionally with "Segmentation Fault". The error rate increased shortly and now it is failing 100%.

```
Traceback:

> OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
> START RequestId: 3b98bd4b-6cda-4d21-8090-1a49b17c06fc Version: $LATEST
> OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
> END RequestId: 3b98bd4b-6cda-4d21-8090-1a49b17c06fc
> REPORT RequestId: 3b98bd4b-6cda-4d21-8090-1a49b17c06fc Duration: 7165.04 ms Billed Duration: 7166 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 41 MB
> RequestId: 3b98bd4b-6cda-4d21-8090-1a49b17c06fc Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
> Runtime.ExitError
```

As `awswrangler` itself requires boto3 & botocore, and they are already in the Lambda environment, I suspected that there might be a conflict of different versions of boto. I tried the same flow by explicitly including boto3 and botocore in the requirements but I am still receiving the same segmentation fault error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Found any solution? I am facing the same problem. & How to handle it in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You could use  AWS X-Ray to get more information on the problem : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-tracing.html

Moreover you might analyze the core dump generated executing your lambda function on a bash shell:

```
  ulimit -c unlimited
  cd /tmp
  ececute your python ...
```

You should find a file named /tmp/core..... that you should analyze with gdb after download. The command "man core" could help you.